# Creating a scrollable game map in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I'm trying to make a TBS game app. The basic premise is that each player has a bunch of stars that are laid out on a 2D map and your goal is to conquer half the total stars.

I'm trying to figure out the best way to set up this game board. I want the board to be bigger than the device's screen (meaning the user will scroll around the map and maybe be able to zoom in/out) and be populated with "star" objects.

Anyone know where I should get started? I've looked at Grid View but that seems to be more fit for populating a limitless list of pictures or something.

Comment: Not sure what this has to do with Android studio? You should look into 2D OpenGL.

Comment: You should use the Canvas or OpenGL, or better yet an exiting game engine like http://www.andengine.org/ or Unity3D

Comment: Thanks- I was just really unaware of things like OpenGL or game engines based off of it and was foolishly trying to make a game from scratch. Got AndEngine and it pretty much solves every problem that's been running through my head.